# How to navigate to view from another project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I develop a library for WinPhone app. This library contains several screens.

If I would like to navigate to another view in the same project I can use code like this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewTaskPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

How can I navigate to view from another (relative) project (my library for example)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do that:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/YOURPROJECTNAME;component/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: I have the next error message:"No XAML was found at the location '/MYPROJECTNAME;View/MainPage.xaml'." Does it mean that I have to upload MYPROJECTNAME to phone?

Comment: MYPROJECTNAME has to be replaced with the name of the project that contains the XAML. That project should be referenced in the main project references.

Comment: Well, I exactly do the same.I added the second project to project dependencies and added dll to references. May be something wrong with project properties? Because I think that resources (like xaml or images) dont copied to main project.

Comment: I found my mistake. "component/" - is not a folder in project, it is a specific part of uri