# Windows Phone 8.1 Navigation from usercontrol

Tags: windows-phone-8, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

I have control , which has navigation buttons . Please tell me how to navigate from a user control on the page.(The project with UserControl is separate from the project with pages).
I tried to use: 
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
But project can have only one relationship.

Comment: What does, `The project with UserControl is separate from the project with pages` mean?

Comment: I have two projects: 1 - have .cs files, 2 - have views (xaml+.cs)

Comment: Is that within the same solution?

Comment: yes. first project for user controls and classes, second for views

Comment: this one might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420182/how-to-navigate-to-another-project-inside-same-solution

Comment: Dear  Kulasangar, it's work only on WP 8.0 and WP 8.1 Silverlight, I have WP 8.1 project

Comment: The answer which is right below talks about WP8.1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420182/how-to-navigate-to-another-project-inside-same-solution#answer-27639612

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry, but I do not know very well English, I 'm trying to find a ready example on my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Worked for me, to navigate from UserControl to Page:

1.
`(Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(MyUserControl));`

2.
  `await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(MyUserControl)));`

Comment: welcome Georgy Gazaryan... if it worked. just give one up vote to my answer. ;)