# Navigation Between Two projects under one Solution WindowsRT

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, windows-rt

I have been working on different projects and I have to navigate through different projects at button Tap or Click event is there any way to achieve this outcome. I searched online and all i could find is for silverlight. How to get the same on windowsRT

[The Link of the silverlight one is as follows:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420182/how-to-navigate-to-another-project-inside-same-solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you navigate to Types in WinRT, it doesn't matter what project your Page is in, as log as you added it as a reference in your current project.